# ButterKnife how to use @OnClick with parameters

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a `TextView` and setting the text by calling `setItem`

```
public void setItem(String text){
    commentsTextView.setText(text);
}
```

With butterknife should be like this:

```
private String mText;

public void setItem(String text){
    mText = text;
}

@OnClick(R.id.commentsTextView)
protected void comment(){
    commentsTextView.setText(mText);
}
```

but this does not look right. What is the right way to use `@OnClick`, with  parameters not just make a Toast like all the examples shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Butter Knife's callbacks are methods on a class so if you want additional parameters those would need to be fields on that class.

Look into [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/427#issuecomment-173011104).

Comment: I see, but when I have more parameters it looks like overhead instead of just setting OnClickListener. And the main purpose of butterknife is to have nicer and cleaner look. Or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the answer from Rikin, I think you are trying to misuse the `@OnClick` annotation. Normally you would pass the `View` and get/set the field from it e.g.

```
@OnClick(R.id.commentsTextView)
    protected void comment(TextView view){
        view.setText(mText);
    }
```

The field `mText` could be set beforehand somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I passed two parameters to `@OnClick`method I got this error: `error: @OnClick methods can have at most 1 parameter(s).`

Comment: @tpbafk You can specify multiple IDs like this `@OnClick({ R.id.door1, R.id.door2, R.id.door3 })`

Answer (score 0):

in you android studio open (just click)   @OnClick interface then you can see the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate fields(BindView, OnClick, ...) in `Butterknife` is need called `Butterknife.bind(...)`

Make sure call `Butterknife.bind` function in your view.